# Printing a webpage without the info at the top and the bottom of the paper page?

Tags: html, printing

I am printing a webpage to give to our customers, but I am getting the URL of the page, the printing date and the number of pages to print.

There is any way to remove that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers and Footers checkbox in the print dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The headers and footers are not added in the webpage, but by the browser or printer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Chrome to print the page. In the Chrome print dialog screen simply uncheck "Headers and footers" in the "Options" section.

Other browsers may also allow you to do this in their print dialog screens too. I, personally, only know of Chrome that offers the function.

Comment: @joe-frambach The answer that was accepted was originally described in my post above... I guess screenshots are preferred to text answers. Noted.